# Use ekkoLigthbox in a react component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I installed an [ekkoLightbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ekko-lightbox) by the npm.

In my webpack I have an following entry:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: "vendor",
                chunks: "all"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which pack all `node_modules` into a `vendor.js` file.

I also have a `main.js` file:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "bootstrap";
import 'ekko-lightbox';

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

`index.js` with the React app:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And component which use a ekkoLightbox plugin (simplified):

`render` method:

```
render() {
    return <Grid>
        <Row>
            <Col lg={12}>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: article.content}} onClick={this.onClick}/>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Grid>;
}
```

`onClick` method (which is called from `render`):

```
onClick = (e) => {
    let $el = $(e.target);

    if ($el.is('img:not(.not-gallery)')) {
        let $img = $el.clone();
        let $a = $('<a href="' + $el.attr('src') + '" data-toggle="lightbox"/>').append($img);
        console.log($a);
        $a.ekkoLightbox();
    }
}
```

After click on image element I get a following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $a.ekkoLightbox is not a function
    at ArticlePage._this.onClick (ArticlePage.js:63)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:542)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:581)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:438)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:452)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:836)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:858)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:956)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:967)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First of all i dont think using jquery with react is a good thing so that would be the first issue...

Comment: since `$a.ekkoLightbox();` seems to be what is causing `$a.ekkoLightbox is not a function`, you should try and `console.log($a)`, see if it is actually something you can call `.ekkoLightbox` on, or if `.ekkoLightbox()` is actually the correct function in the first place

Comment: @Scaramouche using jquery with react is one of the worst practice ever so it's better to find an alternative than to try anything... Jquery is for dom manipulation, react is basicaly building your dom and manipulating it...

Comment: @AndréGomes you see how I'm return body with images, which must be showed as a lightbox galery on click? I didn't found any react lib which can work on concrete html result.

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski not because you didn't find one that you can't build it, that's the principale of open source, to avoid reinventing the wheel, but if you do not find it build it !